# Ways of managing the data in a database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm new to databases and web servers and that kind of thing. So I am looking for information so I can begin to figure out a starting point and options open to me.

I need to have a database that can be accessed by an iPhone app. So logically it will be hosted on a webserver somewhere.

To get/insert the data from/into the database the app would make a HTTP connection to a php file on the same server as the DB which would then insert/return the relevant data. To stop random hackers messing with the DB the app would have some validation code inside it to send to the php file to check that its not a hacker trying to mess with the database. This all making sense or will that not be secure enough.

Now the most confusing part to get my head around is :
I need check every minute has any data in the database become to old and remove it if so. So something needs to be running on the server constantly checking/manageing the database. What would this be? What is commonly used to do this kinda of thing? Is there somekey word for it that i can start searching and reading about to see what options there are?

Thanks for your advise,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need a cron job. Cron is the standard scheduling task application for Unix type systems.

You would have some sort of script that connects to the database and performs a cleanup query, and you would schedule that script via cron.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to have a purge script run via crontab. The script can run every minute and check for old data and remove it.

MySQL version greater than 5.1.6 has inbuilt event scheduler which can be used to schedule periodic jobs inside mysql server itself.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html